# cannot compile Java 9 module with --patch-module in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, java-platform-module-system, java-module

I am trying to acquaint myself with Java 9 modules and how to define them in IntelliJ.  Among other things, I want to solve a split package problem using the `--patch-module` compiler/JVM flag and I don't know how to make it work in IntelliJ.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1 Build #IC 172.3544.35 with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9+180, mixed mode).

This is my source file `MyImmutableList.java`:

```
package com.google.common.collect;

public class MyImmutableList extends RegularImmutableList {
  public MyImmutableList(Object[] array) {
    super(array);     
  }
}
```

It belongs to my module `com.effjava.collect` with `module-info.java`:

```
module com.effjava.collect {
    // do not require module guava; instead patch this module with guava.19-0.jar via:
    // javac --patch-module com.effjava.collect=guava-19.0.jar module-info.java com/google/common/collect/MyImmutableList.java
    //    requires guava;        
    exports com.google.common.collect;
}
```

For the compilation of my modules, I specified the `--patch-module` flag in IntelliJ using `Settings` => `Build,Execution,Deplyoment` => `Compiler` => `Shared build process VM options` as [described here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000093430-JDK-jigsaw-issues-patch-module-specified-more-than-once-for).

The compilation fails because the compiler cannot find the superclass `RegularImmutableList` from the guava library.

The advice provided by IntelliJ is to add a `requires` directive for the guava library to the module descriptor, which of course does not work because the compiler then rightly complains about the split package problem:

> Error:java: module guava reads package com.google.common.collect from both com.effjava.collect and guava

On further investigation, I noticed that the build process issues a warning related to the `--patch-module` flag saying:

> Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
>   "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\java" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true
>
> ... lots of stuff ...
>
> WARNING: Unknown module: com.effjava.collect specified to --patch-module
>
> ... more stuff ...

BTW, I did not know how to get hold of the compiler warnings.  I do not hide them in IntelliJ's message window and yet I cannot see them.  As a workaround, I simply specified bogus compiler flags and let the build process crash so that it emitted the WARNING in its crash report.

Anyway, the build process complains  - while building the module - that the module in question does not exist and for this reason cannot be patched via `--patch-module`.  This complaint does not make sense because I did successfully compile and build my module by typing in the `javac` and `jar`commands manually on the command line level:

```
cd %PROJECTDIR%\com.effjava.collect\src
javac --patch-module com.effjava.collect=../../guava/guava-19.0.jar -d ../../out/production/com.effjava.collect module-info.java com/google/common/collect/MyImmutableList.java
jar --create --file=../../out/artifacts/com_effjava_collect_jar/com.effjava.collect.jar -C ../../out/production/com.effjava.collect .
```

How can I tell IntelliJ's build process that I want to patch my module?

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly that you're trying to patch the module under compilation? If so, I'd guess that that's the problem.

Comment: Why would it be a problem to patch the module under compilation?  It works when I type in the `javac` command by hand.  In fact, I have a batch file that compiles all my modules with the `--patch-module` flag, creates all the modular jars, and eventually runs the main module  with the `--patch-module` flag.  The problem is just with IntelliJ.  How can I tell IntelliJ that I want to patch a module?

Comment: Oops, didn't see that. Well, then I'm out of guesses. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well eventually with the following ***configuration of the IntelliJ***[(Fix version of IDEA-169150)](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169150) -

> ```
> IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Community Edition)
> Build #IC-181.4203.550, built on March 27, 2018
> JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b20 x86_64
> JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
> macOS 10.13.3
> ```

and the ***Java Compiler*** settings for the project as the one in the following screenshot:-

[image: Java compiler configuration]

- Override compiler paramaters per-module
- Select the module
- Add the compilation option to patch (***Note*** - I've used the latest version of the jar)

  ```
  --patch-module com.effjava.collect=/Users/naman.nigam/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/24.1-jre/guava-24.1-jre.jar
  ```

---

Post this select ***Build > Build Project*** and the build completes successfully(though I still see `RegularImmutableList` in `MyImmutableList` as red) for me.

[image]