# Patch Module add Class IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, java-module

Say I have a module of the JDK to which I would like to add a class that interacts with some of its contained classes.

I want to do this in the intelliJ IDEA.

I have found that apparently I need to go to  *“Run->EditConfigurations,”* and there in   *“VM Options”* enter this:

```
--patch-module <module>=<file>
```

However, I am having trouble finding the right arguments as

```
<module>
```

and

```
<file>
```

, and with some examples I found on the net people add *“javac”* before this command, and on others some add an *“--add-“* argument, but I can’t seem to get it just right.

A more concrete example to illustrate my problem: the class I want to add should be patched into

```
“jdk.exampleName”
```

and *interact* with the class

```
"jdk.exampleName\subPackage\subPackage2\ExampleClass.java"
```

I have created, in my own project’s

```
“src\main\java\”
```

a sub package:

```
“jdk\exampleName\InteractorClass.java”
```

, so its complete path is:

```
“src\main\java\jdk\exampleName\InteractorClass.java.java”.
```

The class

```
*InteractorClass*
```

is the class that should interact with

```
*ExampleClass*
```

from above.

At compilation, I receive this error: 
Error:*(1, 1) java: package exists in another module: jdk.exampleName.*

What are the correct arguments to give the VM Options of the

```
“--patch-module <module>=<file>”
```

in this case to make it run?

I tried around a lot, but could not get it to work, the most likely try that also didn’t work, neither with or without “javac” was:

```
--patch-module jdk.exampleName=src\main\java\jdk\exampleName\InteractorClass.java
```

Therefore, what are the correct parameters to specify in this case?

Comment: The format that you last shared seems correct. Just make sure that you're following correct packaging conventions as well. Here is the official documentation on [patching the module content.](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Patching-module-content) Also what version of the IDE are you using?

Comment: Thank you.
I have looked at this documentation before as well, however, since I am a student and lack routine that someone that is working in the field for decades has, with not finding any concrete example anywhere (with example paths and classes), I think I made some sort of newbe mistake, but can’t quite figure out which one. 
Hence, I asked the question here, but tried to keep it as generalized as possible so it may benefit someone else in a similar situation. 
Here are the concrete paths of the two classes (via right click, copy path)

Comment: The class JShellPublicator, located in
IdeaProjects\ObjectVizardFX\src\main\java\jdk\jshell\JShellPublicator.java
Has to interact with the JShell.class, here: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4!\jdk.jshell\jdk\jshell\JShell.class
And this is the concrete “VM options argument”
--patch-module jdk.jshell=src\main\java\jdk\jshell\JShellPublicator.java
Am I committing some newbe mistake somewhere like having a slash in my argument where there should be a dot or something?(or missing a package)? I have tried anything I could find or come up with but its sadly not working.Thank you for your time.

Comment: IDE Version: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4(Community Edition)
Build#IC-173.4548.28 built on January 20,2018

Comment: Could be an intelliJ issue as well, another such thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545718/cannot-compile-java-9-module-with-patch-module-in-intellij-idea-2017-2-1

Comment: I have looked at this before, but since I received a different error message (“Error:(1, 1) java: package exists in another module: jdk.jshell”) and his (“Error:Abnormal build process termination: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9\bin\java" -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true”), I, due to  my error message sounding like the IDE didn’t even try the patch, I naturally assumed that I made a mistake somewhere in the patch command rather than it being an IDE Issue. Thank You for pointing this out.

Comment: About the packages, JShell resides in two subpackages called again jdk.jshell, however, If I mirror that structure, (add extra packages jdk.jshell so the complete is jdk.jshell.jdk.jshell.ExampleClass, my class cant access  JShell any more, [i.e. its  KeyMaps I need access to], as if it was in the same package). Hence this subPackage1\subPackage2 only being present in one of the paths from above.